# Can lambda parameter types be left off if potentially inferable from context?

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf

[This Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113359/56183) (and [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76050/56183)) uses a lambda that does not explicitly declare its parameter type, but [this Scala answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113306/56183) includes a parameter type. in both cases, the type could be inferred when it is assigned to a variable. For example, for a lambda that takes an int and returns an int:

```java
Function<Integer, Integer> f = a->... // Java
```

```scala
val f: Int => Int = a=>... // Scala
```

My question is: should the type parameters be included in the lambda, or can we assume that they are declared as above?

Comment: Is there any problem with being able to handle more input types than mandated by the spec?

Comment: @JanDvorak what do you mean?

Comment: @Poke I think that answers it.